# fscanf multiple lines [c++]

Tags: c++, scanf

I am reading in a file with multiple lines of data like this:

```
:100093000202C4C0E0E57FB40005D0E0020C03B463
:1000A3000105D0E0022803B40205D0E0027C03027C
:1000B30002E3C0E0E57FB40005D0E0020C0BB4011D
```

I am reading in values byte by byte and storing them in an array.

```
    fscanf_s(in_file,"%c", &sc);  // start code
    fscanf_s(in_file,"%2X", &iByte_Count); // byte count
    fscanf_s(in_file,"%4X", &iAddr);    // 2 byte address 
    fscanf_s(in_file,"%2X", &iRec_Type);  // record type 

    for(int i=0; i<iByte_Count; i++)
    {
        fscanf_s(in_file,"%2X", &iData[i]);
        iArray[(iMaskedAddr/16)][iMaskedNumMove+3+i]=iData[i];
    }
    fscanf_s(in_file,"%2X", &iCkS);
```

This is working great except when I get to the end of the first line. I need this to repeat until I get to the end of the file but when I put this in a loop it craps out.
Can I force the position to the begining of the next line?
I know I can use a stream and all that but I am dealing with this method.
Thanks for the help

Comment: Do you really have to use fscanf_s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion is to dump `fscanf_s` and use either `fgets` or `std::getline`.

That said, your issue is handling the newlines, and the next beginning of record token, the ':'.

One method is to use `fscanf_s("%c")` until the ':' character is read or the end of file is reached:

```
char start_of_record;
do
{
  fscanf_s(infile, "%c", &start_of_record);
} while (!feof(infile) && (start_of_record != ':'));
// Now process the header....
```

The data the OP is reading is a standard format for transmitting binary data, usually for downloading into Flash Memories and EPROMs.

Answer (score 0):

Your topic clear states that you are using C++ so, if I may, I suggest you use the correct STL stream manipulators.

To read line-by-line, you can use [ifstream::getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/getline/). But again, you are not reading the file line by line, you are reading it field by field. So, you should try using [ifstream::read](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/read/), which lets you choose the amount of bytes to read from the stream.

**UPDATE:**

While doing an unrelated search over the net, I found out about a library called IOF which may help you with this task. [Check it out.](http://iof.sourceforge.net/)